Ground connection of power converter and MCU
I've designed an AC/DC power converter PCB, with input, and output voltage sensing, but I have problem connecting it to microcontroller board, i'm using F28379D launchpad as the microcontroller.
I will use external +5v to supply the launchpad.
Below is a simplified block diagram for the whole system, without going in details of the power converter circuit.
My question is:
Do I have to tie the two grounds together (POWER GND & CONTROL GND) for proper measurement, and if I have to do so, is it safe for the launchpad?


Is the AC voltage signal from the converter isolated?

yes it is, I am using this AC sensor module
https://www.amazon.in/Voltage-Sensor-Module-ZMPT101B-Single/dp/B099X86B1H
